# Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long when trying to post dictionary of values to API

Tags: c#, http, post, uri

The below code is constructing a post request to an API but in some instances the html_text is massive (70,000 characters+) which seems to be too much causing a `Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long` error and I cannot find a way to overcome this.

How do I increase the effective URI limit?

```
public async Task<string> CreateCampaign(string apiKey, string fromName, string fromEmail, string replyTo, string title,
            string subject, string plaintext, string htmltext, string listIds, string segmentIds, string excludeListIds,
            string excludeSegmentIds, string brandId, string queryString, string sendCampaign)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "api_key", apiKey },
               { "from_name", fromName },
               { "from_email", fromEmail },
               { "reply_to", replyTo },
               { "title", title },
               { "subject", subject },
               { "plain_text", plaintext },
               { "html_text", htmltext },
               { "list_ids", listIds },
               { "segment_ids", segmentIds },
               { "exclude_list_ids", excludeListIds },
               { "exclude_segment_ids", excludeSegmentIds },
               { "brand_id", brandId },
               { "query_string", queryString },
               { "send_campaign", sendCampaign },

            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("[Redacted-DOMAIN]/api/campaigns/create.php", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormUrlEncodedContent is restricted in size.

The server accept JSON? If so you cold try this:

```
var content = new StringContent(serializedValues, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

instead of

```
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
```

If not you can try to use  [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22369#issuecomment-343317124) workaround:

```
 var items = formData.Select(i => WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Value));
var content = new StringContent(String.Join("&", items), null, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: Sorry - it doesn't looks like it accepts JSON I'm afraid